# Is there a tool to perform analytics similar to code-forensics but for organization level view?

Tags: reporting, github

I actively use [Code-forensics](https://github.com/smontanari/code-forensics) but now i want it to be expanded for organization level. I am also looking for getting an holistic overview of-

- Github organization performance
- Org level build reports – consolidated build reporting
- Story consolidations and performance per sprint
- Developer efficiency at org level
- Along with GitHub data, aggregation of CI Server, Sonar Server data should be possible.

Kindly recommend an approach here without using any hosted solution.